# Windows 11 security connection issues

Tags: lsass, windows-11

I applied a windows update to Windows 11 and since then I have been unable to connect to remote machines using MSTSC, the error is *"An authentication error has occured. The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted."* I can connect to the same remote machine from other sources. Googling this focuses on fixing the remote machine, which I have proven isnt the issue.

I have also tried to connect to other items using other technology and I am getting errors. For example, connecting to Azure Service Bus using AzureServiceBusExplorer fails leading to the following error *"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."*

Trying to connect from Visual Studio to Azure DevOps has the following error *"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."*

Googling these two errors has a lot of solutions on fixing your SSL certificate on your website, but this isn't the issue here.

If I put fiddler on I can see no HTTPS calls are successful. The error in Fiddler is *"HTTPS handshake to live.com failed. System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. < The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted"* Strangely I can still browse the internet with Chrome and Edge but it is slower

I think this is something local to this machine at fault but I can't figure out what it is. I have googled around as you can see but can't get a decent grasp of what to look for.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated

UPDATE: I have fixed the issue by restoring a week old backup of the machine, I know this doesn't help future visits to this question but I wanted to flag that it was proven to be a local machine issue

Comment: Did you make any changes on network ? DNS ?

Comment: Other machines on this network (that use the same DNS) are all functioning without issue. This led me to rule out network wide issues.